# Split 1 row into multiple rows of hourly data based on datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that shows who is booking which room at which timing and it looks like this.

```
email         room   Start Date           End Date
abc@corp.com  L11M2  2021-02-01 08:00:00  2021-02-01 11:00:00
xyz@corp.com  L12M4  2021-02-01 08:00:00  2021-02-01 10:00:00
```

I want to split this up into different hours such that one row only contains one hour of data.
This is the dataframe that I want to get.

```
email         room   Start Date           End Date
abc@corp.com  L11M2  2021-02-01 08:00:00  2021-02-01 09:00:00
abc@corp.com  L11M2  2021-02-01 09:00:00  2021-02-01 10:00:00
abc@corp.com  L11M2  2021-02-01 10:00:00  2021-02-01 11:00:00
xyz@corp.com  L12M4  2021-02-01 08:00:00  2021-02-01 09:00:00
xyz@corp.com  L12M4  2021-02-01 09:00:00  2021-02-01 10:00:00
```

Is there any way that I can do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `pandas.date_range` and `explode`:

```
df['Start Date'] = df.apply(lambda d: pd.date_range(d['Start Date'],
                                                    d['End Date'], 
                                                    freq='h')[:-1], 
                            axis=1)
df = df.explode('Start Date')
df['End Date'] = df['Start Date'] + pd.Timedelta('1h')
```

output:

```
          email   room          Start Date            End Date
0  abc@corp.com  L11M2 2021-02-01 08:00:00 2021-02-01 09:00:00
0  abc@corp.com  L11M2 2021-02-01 09:00:00 2021-02-01 10:00:00
0  abc@corp.com  L11M2 2021-02-01 10:00:00 2021-02-01 11:00:00
1  xyz@corp.com  L12M4 2021-02-01 08:00:00 2021-02-01 09:00:00
1  xyz@corp.com  L12M4 2021-02-01 09:00:00 2021-02-01 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of pandas `melt`, with pyjanitor's `complete` could help transform the data:

```
 # pip install pyjanitor
 import pandas as pd
 import janitor
(df.melt(['email', 'room'], value_name = 'Start_Date')
.reindex([3,1,2,0])
 # complete is a wrapper around pandas functions
 # to expose missing values ... in this case it exposes the 
 # missing dates for each group in by
.complete([{'Start_Date':lambda df: pd.date_range(df.min(), df.max(),freq='H')}], 
           by=['email', 'room'])
.assign(End_Date = lambda df: df.Start_Date.add(pd.Timedelta('1 hour')))
.query('variable != "End Date"').drop(columns='variable'))

          email   room          Start_Date            End_Date
0  abc@corp.com  L11M2 2021-02-01 08:00:00 2021-02-01 09:00:00
1  abc@corp.com  L11M2 2021-02-01 09:00:00 2021-02-01 10:00:00
2  abc@corp.com  L11M2 2021-02-01 10:00:00 2021-02-01 11:00:00
4  xyz@corp.com  L12M4 2021-02-01 08:00:00 2021-02-01 09:00:00
5  xyz@corp.com  L12M4 2021-02-01 09:00:00 2021-02-01 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some sample data

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ref = now.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
def shifted(i): return ref + timedelta(hour=i)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('A', 'B', shifted(1), shifted(10)), 
    ('C', 'D', shifted(-5), shifted(-1))], 
    columns=['name', 'email', 'start', 'end'])
```

The data looks like this

```
  name email               start                 end
0    A     B 2021-08-27 12:00:00 2021-08-27 21:00:00
1    C     D 2021-08-27 06:00:00 2021-08-27 05:00:00
```

You can split up each row with the `apply` function, making sure you return a `pd.Series`.

```
new_start = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(pd.date_range(row.start, row.end, freq='H')), axis=`).stack()
```

After this, `new_start` is the start of every hour, with a double index, one is the original index and one is the order of that particular block, could be useful as well.

```
0  0   2021-08-27 12:00:00
   1   2021-08-27 13:00:00
   2   2021-08-27 14:00:00
   3   2021-08-27 15:00:00
   4   2021-08-27 16:00:00
   5   2021-08-27 17:00:00
   6   2021-08-27 18:00:00
   7   2021-08-27 19:00:00
   8   2021-08-27 20:00:00
   9   2021-08-27 21:00:00
1  0   2021-08-27 06:00:00
   1   2021-08-27 07:00:00
   2   2021-08-27 08:00:00
   3   2021-08-27 09:00:00
   4   2021-08-27 10:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now just join this to the original frame.

```
res = df[["name", "email"]].join(
new_start.reset_index(1, drop=True).rename("start"))
```

And you can add the `end` column like this

```
res["end"] = res.start + timedelta(hours=1)
```